# pygtk gtk.combo_box_new_text() with a default value

Tags: pygtk, gtk

```
    cb.append_text('Firefox')
    cb.append_text('Chrome')
    cb.append_text('Opera')
```

[image]

nothing displayed until I clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cb.set_active(0)
```

couldn't submit answer until I added padding